# How to get polymorphic relationships in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-7

I've 3 models and migrations in laravel app where used Polymorphic Relationships

**Models**

- Attribute
- AttributeValue
- ModelHasAttribute

**Migrations**

Attribute

```
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

AttributeValue

```
Schema::create('attribute_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('value');
    $table->foreignId('attribute_id')->constrained();
    $table->uuidMorphs('model');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

ModelHasAttribute

```
Schema::create('model_has_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('attribute_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('attribute_value_id')->constrained();
    $table->uuidMorphs('model');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now here all attributes will be created only using **Attribute** model and values for attribute will be created using all another models, e.g in my case **Category** model.

**Category** class has like this relationship method inside:

```
public function attributeValues()
{
    return $this->morphMany(AttributeValue::class, 'model');
}
```

**Question:** How I can get all attributes with there values inside **Category** model and what do you think, my relationships is correct or can be better?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('value');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('attributable_id');
    $table->string('attributable_type');
});
```

Then in Attribute model:

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function attributable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

In Catgeory model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Attribute::class, 'attributable');
    }
}
```

Edit:

If you really want to have one to many attribute values per attribute:

In migrations:

```
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('attributable_id');
    $table->string('attributable_type');
});

Schema::create('attribute_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('value');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('attribute_id');
    
    $table->foreign('attribute_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('attributes')
});
```

Then in Attribute class:

```
    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class);
    }
```

and AttributeValue class:

```
class AttributeValue extend Model
{
    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Attribute:class);
    }
}
```

Now I cant remember if hasManyThrough works with polymorphic relationships, but:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Attribute::class, 'attributable');
    }

    public function attributeValues()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(AttributeValue::class, Attribute::class)
    }
}
```